# how to countif, if i want to conunt over 100% results in not a consecutive column?

Tags: excel, countif

if there are texts and numbers(%) mixed in column(A1:A6), how can I count those numbers which are over 100%? for example

```
ex. A B C D E
1 text
2 90%
3 text
4 120%
5 text
6 150%
```

using countif or Suggest me

Comment: Use the isnumber criteria in your countif, combined with a second criteria >1 / >100, depending on the settings of your cell,  That would result in 2 in your example.

Answer (score 0):

`COUNTIF` will ignore the text values if you use a numeric criterion, so you can use just a simple

`=COUNTIF(A1:A6,">100%")`